# .htaccess overwrite the deny ip list and allow a one single ip in any case?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

in .htaccess i have following entries to block some certain country ip's  however list is so long, its impossible to match a ip address pattern in there one by one for certain ip address,

but i want to add a certain ip address to be allowed even if that matched "deny pattern"

how do i do this ? i tried

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order allow,deny
deny from 123.2.220.
deny from 203.171.196.
....
# this list is long 
....
....
allow from 222.165.128.0/18
</Limit>
```

but this last ip if that matched the top it still get blocked ? how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `order allow,deny` to `order deny,allow`.

Note that once this is done, any `Allow` will override a `Deny` - an `Allow from all` would render all of your `Deny`s completely inert.

Depending on your configuration, it might make more sense to simply find the `Deny` line that's applying to an IP range and remove it (or break it up to avoid blocking the range you're interested in).